# Why we define pool for declaring CISCO router DHCP?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, dhcp

In case declaring DHCP server in CISCO routers, should define pool with network addresses.↓

**Example**

`Router(config)#ip dhcp pool net1`

`Router(dhcp-config)#network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0`

The router has predefined interfaces *ip address* and *subnet mask*.

Thus for **each interface** can only define dhcp service *enable* or *disable*? **and** dhcp options. **and** `excluded-address`.

**Why should we write `Router(dhcp-config)#network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` ?**

Comment: You can also use the DHCP server for non-connected networks, so you must define the network for the pool.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you so much. You find my mean clearly!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

Router(config)# ip DHCP pool vlan10
Router(dhcp-config)# network 192 .168.1.0 255.255.255.0

This command is mentioned beacuse desktops in  vlan10 will get ip allocation from this pool of ip network..

Vlan 10 allocated desktop will get DHCP ip range from 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255  dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Router will automatically know which interface is associated with which DHCP Pool. You create a network for the pool, exclude the addresses like static hosts or reserved addresses, provide default gateway and DNS servers (you can edit few different DHCP options if needed). Based on default gateway and the network, router associates it with either the interface or vlan.